# How to get response and reply to sms using Twilio with C# Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-api

How to get response and reply to sms using Twilio with C# Asp.net. How do I Send Outbound SMS Text Messages?

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from an article I wrote on setting up Twilio and our Conveyor extension (free, go to Tools->Extensions) for development locally.

We will use Conveyor to provide incoming access to our web project through a tunnel, enabling your webhooks to be called on localhost. Conveyor is available through the Tools->Extensions menu, by searching for conveyor.

**Setup an MVC Web Application**
To get started, we’re going to setup a simple webhooks MVC demo app in Visual Studio. We will use the Twilio service to notify our application when a text message (SMS) has been received and respond with a specific message. This tutorial can also be used for Twilio's other API's including Chat, Voice and Video.

This example project is designed to show you how Conveyor can be used to simplify the use of webhooks on your local machine. If you need more details about how to setup webhooks please look online at numerous tutorials and projects.

Create a new project, we’ll be creating an empty ASP.NET MVC C# project. We won’t be hosting in the Cloud so don’t select Azure.

[image]

**Add NuGet Packages**
In order to use the Twilio helper libraries we will need to install the Twilio NuGet package via the Package Manager console. Enter the following line and hit return;

```
     Install-Package Twilio.AspNet.Mvc -DependencyVersion HighestMinor
```

**Create a new Controller**
To listen for the Twilio webhook we’ll create an MVC Controller. Twilio will call our webhook once an SMS text message has been received.

Right click the Controllers folder in your project, select Add > Controller and add an empty MVC 5 Controller. You can name your Controller as you see fit.

[image]

Next you will need to add the using statements to import the Twilio namespaces;

```
        using Twilio.AspNet.Common;
        using Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;
        using Twilio.TwiML;
```

and change the Controller class to inherit from TwilioController.

Now we add the following code;

```
        [HttpPost]
        public TwiMLResult Index(SmsRequest request)
        {
            var response = new MessagingResponse();
            response.Message("Hello World");
            return TwiML(response);
        }
```

Of course you can code your webhook however you need but for our example, we have our response message set as “Hello World” so when our webhook receives notification of a SMS text to our Twilio number, it will respond with our own message.

**Run the Application**
So now we can go ahead and run our application. As this is a simple project with the only content being our Controller, you will see an error page. That doesn’t matter, we just need our project to be running in Visual Studio so we can make use of the webhook.

[image]

**Use Conveyor**
Now the application is running, we can use Conveyor to obtain a publically accessible URL that we can provide to Twilio. Clicking Access Over Internet in the Conveyor window will then provide us with the URL we need. You may need to register an account at this point.

Calls to the conveyor.cloud URL are tunnelled to your localhost, so we will add the Controller name to the conveyor.cloud URL and then add it to the Twilio settings.

[image]

That’s it. We’re ready to test it out!

Now when I send a SMS text to my Twilio number the message from our application is sent back to the original mobile number.

[image]